# Gatsby: Context update causes infinite render loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

I am trying to update context once a Gatsby page loads.

The way I did it, the context is provided to all pages, and once the page loads the context is updated (done with `useEffect` to ensure it only happens when the component mounts).

Unfortunately, this causes an infinite render loop (perhaps not in Firefox, but at least in Chrome).

Why does this happen? I mean, the context update means all the components below the provider are re-rendered, but the useEffect should only run once, and thats when the component mounts.

Here is the **code**: https://codesandbox.io/s/6l3337447n

The infinite loop happens when you go to page two (link at bottom of page one).

What is the solution here, if I want to update the context whenever a page loads?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, `useEffect` runs every render. In your example, `useEffect` updates the `context` every render, thus trigger an infinite loop.

There's this bit in the [React doc:](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#tip-optimizing-performance-by-skipping-effects)

> If you want to run an effect and clean it up only once (on mount and unmount), you can pass an empty array ([]) as a second argument. This tells React that your effect doesn’t depend on any values from props or state, so it never needs to re-run. This isn’t handled as a special case — it follows directly from how the dependencies array always works.

So applies to your example:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("CONTEXT DATA WHEN PAGE 2 LOADS:", data)
    mergeData({
      location,
    })
-  }, [location, mergeData, data])
+  }, [])
```

This way, `useEffect` only runs on first mount. I think you can also leave `location` in there, it will also prevent the infinite loop since `useEffect` doesn't depend on the value from `context`.

Comment: Thank you, Derek! Any idea why it updates when specifying `[location, mergeData, data]`? I mean, `mergeData` is a function, that does not change. `location` should not change on re-render, because the route remains unchanged. Similarly, `data` is set to `location`, so that should not change either. And lastly, `mergeData` is just a function which definitely does not change. PS: I owe you a follow-up on the previous post, but I need to tackle a couple of other pressing matters first..

Comment: Interesting, I think I figured out the answer to my above question. It is the variable `data` that causes `useEffect` to fire when re-rendering. Both `location` and `mergeData` remain unchanged. This probably comes back to the fact that the `spread` syntax, which I am using in `context.js`, actually merges a *clone* of the `location` object, into the context `data` object. Thus, on each context update, `data` is a new object. Aha, that must be it! Source on `spread`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#Spread_in_object_literals

Comment: @Magnus Sorry about the late reply, I think you're spot on there!

Comment: This is incorrect. See here about [exhaustive-deps](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/14920)

Comment: @temporaryfix What is incorrect? Would you elaborate?

Comment: You are passing an empty array when `useEffect` has a dependency on `mergeData`, `data`, and `location`. You must specify all dependencies in the dependency array. None should be omitted as outlined in the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html). This is answer is wrong.

Comment: The main excerpt from the docs is `If you use this optimization, make sure the array includes all values from the component scope (such as props and state) that change over time and that are used by the effect. Otherwise, your code will reference stale values from previous renders. Learn more about how to deal with functions and what to do when the array changes too often.`

Comment: The correct answer is to wrap the context's `mergeData` in a `useCallback` hook so that the function does not cause an infinite loop in `useEffect`

Comment: @TemporaryFix ah thanks! I have forgotten the issue in the question, but thought my answer didn't state anything wrong. Thanks for clarifying, hope OP can see & mark your answer as correct.

Comment: I spent a good chunk of yesterday banging my head against the wall on this issue because I also attempted to remove the dependencies which fixed the loop but I kept receiving a warning in the console `Line 113:6:  React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: ‘getContextValue’. Either include it or remove the dependency array  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps`.

Answer (score 1):

The correct answer for this issue is not to pass an empty dependency array to `useEffect` but to wrap your context's `mergeData` in a `useCallback` [hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback). I'm unable to edit your code but you may also need to add dependencies to your `useCallback` like in my example below

```
import React, { useState, useCallback } from "react"

const defaultContextValue = {
  data: {
    // set initial data shape here
    menuOpen: false,
  },
  mergeData: () => {},
}

const Context = React.createContext(defaultContextValue)
const { Provider } = Context

function ContextProviderComponent({ children }) {
  const [data, setData] = useState({
    ...defaultContextValue,
    mergeData, // shorthand method name
  })

  const mergeData = useCallback((newData) {
    setData(oldData => ({
      ...oldData,
      data: {
        ...oldData.data,
        ...newData,
      },
    }))
  }, [setData])

  return <Provider value={data}>{children}</Provider>
}

export { Context as default, ContextProviderComponent }
```

The selected answer is incorrect because the react docs explicitly say not to omit dependencies that are used within the effect which the current selected answer is suggesting.

If you use `es-lint` with the [eslint-plugin-react-hooks](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-react-hooks#installation) it will tell you this is incorrect.

> Note
>
> If you use this optimization, make sure the array includes all values
> from the component scope (such as props and state) that change over
> time and that are used by the effect. Otherwise, your code will
> reference stale values from previous renders. Learn more about how to
> deal with functions and what to do when the array changes too often.

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html

> Is it safe to omit functions from the list of dependencies? Generally
> speaking, no. It’s difficult to remember which props or state are used
> by functions outside of the effect. This is why usually you’ll want to
> declare functions needed by an effect inside of it. Then it’s easy to
> see what values from the component scope that effect depends on:

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#is-it-safe-to-omit-functions-from-the-list-of-dependencies